# xslt code choose between maximum of 2 values

Tags: xslt

I have this xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<racine>
  <index>
    <Parent nom="00000002" Name="" Address="" />
    <Meter numSerie="00000002" />
    <arrêté dateArrêté="28/02/2015 00:00:00">
      <ValeurIndex Libelle="Val1">23.334</ValeurIndex>
      <ValeurIndex Libelle="Val2">5.186</ValeurIndex>
      <ValeurIndex Libelle="Val3">2.79</ValeurIndex>
      </arrêté>
  </index>
</racine>
```

and I would like to  convert it in a txt file, where I need to add a new row with the value of max between Val1 and Val2, as the example below.

```
Val1,23.334
Val2,5.186
Val3,2.79
MaxVal1Vl2,23.334
```

What I created it was something like:

```
<xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@Libelle = 'Val1'">Val1</xsl:when>    
      <xsl:when test="@Libelle = 'Val2'">Val2</xsl:when>    
      <xsl:when test="@Libelle = 'Val3'">Val3</xsl:when>    
  </xsl:choose>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>
```

how can I add the 4 row being the max of Val1 and Val2?

Thanks

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: It is XSLT 1.0 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/racine">
    <xsl:for-each select="index/arrêté/ValeurIndex">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Libelle"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:variable name="v1" select="index/arrêté/ValeurIndex[@Libelle='Val1']" />
    <xsl:variable name="v2" select="index/arrêté/ValeurIndex[@Libelle='Val2']" />
    <xsl:text>MaxVal1Vl2,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$v1 > $v2">
            <xsl:value-of select="$v1"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$v2"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```